# Create WPF Form with OpenGL window(viewport) using OpenTK

Tags: c#, wpf, opentk

I'm trying to create a WPF form with an openGL window, for this I'm using openTK.
In VS2022, I create a WPF form and install openTK v4.7.4 and openTK.GLControl v3.1.0 via nuget. The project uses .NET 6.0.

In code I add

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
```

In xaml add

```
<WindowsFormsHost Initialized="WindowsFormsHost_Initialized" Name="glControl" Margin="136,0,4,0"/>
```

In function

```
private void WindowsFormsHost_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var flags = GraphicsContextFlags.Default;
    glControl = new GLControl(new GraphicsMode(32, 24), 2, 0, flags);
}
```

And the openGL functions are not available to me, swears at GraphicsContextFlags.Default; and GLControl(new GraphicsMode(32, 24), 2, 0, flags);

Also, when installing openTK, a warning is issued:
Warning NU1701 Package "OpenTK.GLControl 3.1.0" has been restored with ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4. 7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8" and not the project target framework "net6.0-windows7.0". This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Why you not use OpenTK.GLControl, It is deprecated and no longer recommended.?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73060252/1136211